# Table lock in SSIS transaction

Tags: sql-server, ssis, transactions

I have a SSIS package with as `OnError` event handler

Under my Package (TransactionOption is required) i do the following

Read a pending status record from a table `SampleTable` using for each loop(TransactionOption is supported)

Update that record status as 'In progress'.

...other statements...

Update that record status as 'Completed'. End.

I have an OnError event handler. Under event handler i am updating the status as failed in the same record of SampleTable and it couse the tableloack (in both suppoprted/notsupportde mode). Actually here i am trying to rollback all the changes i made under the Control flow and data flow level, except event handler.
Now package is stuck on event handler when i updates same 'SampleTable' record status column as 'failed' (due to the transaction lock).

Comment: So, what is the question or problem you are asking assistance? Transaction Rollback cleans up all changes, including those of OnError error handler?

Comment: @Ferdipux, I want to keep the data changes from error handler. Now package is stuck on event handler when i updates same 'SampleTable' record status column as 'failed' (due to the transaction lock).

Answer (score 2):

**The problem cause** - You are trying to change the same table and same table record inside a transaction and with Error Handler. Error Handler is fired right after the erroneous task, it does not wait for task completion and transaction rollback. So, your table and row in this table is locked inside transaction scope, and Event Handler tries to modify the same record; transaction will be aborted only **after** Event Handler completion. This is classical deadlock situation.

**Solution** - change your approach. Error Handler should not try to modify the same data which is processed in the main block. Either - enclose all all-in-one tasks in a Sequence Container, and add the next task - set record error status with precedence constraint - *Failure* (like on the picture). The Sequence Container can have *TransactionOption=Required* to organize transaction.   [image: Sample error task precedence]

Alternative - you can use Error handler, with *TransactionOption=NotSupported* (not to be rolled back), and write erroneous record id and additional info into some other table (to avoid locking). Then later in the package task flow - process this error information and update record state.

Comment: I modified the Package as 'Suppored', ForEachLoopContainer as 'Required' and EventHandler as 'NotSupported'. But still issue there.

Comment: @AbdulRasheed, did you define EventHandler on FEL, not on Package level?

Comment: Yes checked OnError handler in both FEL and Package level. And what i have to specify in OnError, 'NotSupported'?

Comment: @AbdulRasheed, Has the FEL transaction rolled back before ErrorHandler start to work? It seems that table is locked inside incomplete transaction, and OnError tries to update it.

Comment: FEL transaction not rolled back before ErrorHandler. But if i remove the update query (status=failed) from OnError it will work and rolled back without any issue.

Comment: @AbdulRasheed, reworked your problem cause and recommendations.